# store object file when phone is shutted down and retrieve the file when the phone is rebooted

Tags: android, android-file

I have saved an object of a class in a file in my application, when the phone shuts down, what happens to the file? I think, the file get lost. because after reboot my phone, I get null values(which are saved in some variables in the class object) from the file. How can I make sure that, the file will not get lost if the phone is shutted down. Is it possible?

Comment: You can save your file in sdcard so you don't need to worry about the file because the file will be stored in sdcard permanently.

Comment: @ricintech is wirght, you should store your file on sdcard

Comment: how can i save my file in sdcard? so far i have open a file and write object of the class in the file ... please, can you give me some suggestion about, how can i save my file in SDcard? @ricintech

Comment: Use this link: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Comment: If you can already write to a file, moving it (from the internal storage) to the sdcard will not help with your problem.  Your challenge would be more to determine the appropriate time to save information - for which there is no absolute answer.  Doing it in any of onPause(), onStop(), or onDestroy() is a possibility (at least if it's a quick operation) but each has it's own tradeoffs, primarily frequency of unnecessary saving vs possibility of the app dying without getting a chance to save.  Also you will need to learn how to serialize your class in order to store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i serialize my class like:

```
public class MyStore implements Serializable {
    //this serialVersionUID will automatically generate
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3487640153579137276L;
......
......
}
```

then i have saved the object in internal memory like this:

```
File path = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), foldar_name);
path.mkdirs();
File file = new File(path,file_name);
file.createNewFile();

MyStore myStore = new MyStore();                            
myStore.setData(my_data);

FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
os.writeObject(myStore);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this code:

```
String filename = "filename.txt";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
FileOutputStream fos;
byte[] data = new String("data to write to file").getBytes();
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(data);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

And make sure you have declared the permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: is the file, written in the SDcard, in Context.private_mode or in Context.public_mode @ricintech

Comment: can i make it private? if yes, how? @ricintech

Comment: Please do NOT accept this answer - it is entirely tangential to your question.  And no, you cannot make a file on the external storage private - you can encrypt it which might prevent another app from making sense of it, but you can't prevent another app from overwriting or erasing it.

Comment: Use your application's [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) if you want to create application-private files.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using Preferences. Writing to external storage is generally a bad idea. Use SharedPreferences to save the state of the object and instantiating that object again with the data you saved.

[SharedPreferences API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)